# different URI scheme across different android version when trying to open a file

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to use my app to open a file from external storage.
I am using Share via feature.

my code Export

```
File filelocation = new File(sPath);
Uri path = Uri.fromFile(filelocation);
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");

emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
String mystring = ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.Import_rule);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mystring);
```

Import function

```
if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(in.getAction()))
{
    uri = (Uri) in.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);

   uri.getPath();

}
```

When i try to get the `uri.getPath()`  i see difference in differnt devices versions.

in Android 5.0 devicve :

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/DeviceList.zip
```

in Android 6.0  device

```
content://0@media/external/file/1147
```

- I dont know why the URI scheme is different across versions?
- How can i resolve this?
- Can you tell me how can i read from content and save as file

Answer (score 1):

> I dont know why the URI scheme is different across versions?

`content` has been a valid scheme since Android 1.0. It is has been preferred for years due to better security. It will become extremely important in the future, as [Android N is beginning to ban `file` `Uri` values](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/14/psa-file-scheme-ban-n-developer-preview.html).

Also, please note that change in schemes this has little to do with the Android OS version. It has more to do with the version of the app you are using to trigger the `ACTION_SEND` `Intent`.

> How can i resolve this?

Support both of them.

> Can you tell me how can i read from content and save as file

[Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html) to get an `InputStream` on the content pointed to by the `Uri`. Then, use Java I/O to copy that data to a local file.